# URL.createObjectURL(blob) - Image src is not showing the Image

Tags: css, reactjs, image, createobjecturl

I have received the `blob` object as a response and It constructs the below Image tag using `URL.createObjectURL(blob)`.

`<image src="blob:http://localhost/someblobhax: />`.

Unfortunately, the image is not showing/rendering in the UI. can you please suggest
appropriate syntax.